# Persistent properties in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

With Codeigniter 2.xx, how can I keep the values of properties set between method calls that require new HTTP request?  I'm am trying to avoid getting and setting the same data multiple times.  Example of current:
Model:

```
class Plan_model extends Ci_model{
     public $plan_id;
     public function __construct()
     {
         parent::construct(); 
     }

     public function set_plan_id($plan_id) 
     {
        $this->plan_id = $plan_id; //Becomes NULL with new http request, want to keep value  
     }
}
```

Controller:

```
class Plan extends Ci_controller{

     public function __construct()
     {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('plan_model');
     }

    public function set_plan_id()
    { 
       $this->plan_model->set_plan_id(3)
       redirect('/plan/get_plan_id');
    }

    public function get_plan_id()
    {
       $plan_id = $this->plan_model->plan_id; //produces NULL, Expecting 3
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking at using sessions to define the info.

```
$this->session->set_userdata($plan_id);
```

Here's the link for session data: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: I know I could store the value in the session...but is there no way to stop re instantiating the model object with each new http request?

Comment: Not really, except to test for the needed value before instantiating.  You could instantiate the model if the session variable isn't set.  Is there a performance issue you're running into in re-instantiating?